# Rails 3.1 Compass and Sprockets. Confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

I am generally confused about Rails 3.2, Sprockets, and Compass.

1. At the top of this [article](http://rule52.com/2011/06/sass-and-sprockets-for-rails-31/), it says `*= require directives`, are no longer needed using Sass-Rails, just use `@import` instead. The Sass-Rails Github talks about a little about glob `@import` feature, but doesn't talk at all about `@import` being the new `*= require`. Which one or combo :( 
   do I use?
2. Having `coderay.css.sass` in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` and using `@import` in `application.css.sass` will import `my_coderay.css.sass`?
   I don't know because I'm using Compass Mixins in `my_coderay.css.sass` (thus putting a `@import "compass/css3"` at the top of that file) and I'm getting an error:
   **"File to import not found or unreadable: compass"**
3. In this [article](http://metaskills.net/2011/07/29/use-compass-sass-framework-files-with-the-rails-3.1.0.rc5-asset-pipeline/) it talks about configuring Rail's Sass engine to know about the assets path. But I thought Sass-Rails *already* teaches `@import` where asset path is?

   Also when I try to include the 31 branch of compass...

   `gem 'compass', :git => 'git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git', :branch => 'rails31'`

   I get errors...
   Using compass (0.12.0.alpha.0.22e2458) from git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git (at rails31) /Users/george.norris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:365:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /Users/george.norris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/gems/compass-0.12.0.alpha.0.22e2458/bin/compass (Errno::ENOENT)
4. And finally, if I take `coderay.css.sass` out of vendor/assets and put it in app/assets I don't get the above error. But I getting it's spitting out errors in public/application.css.css (.css.css ???)

   Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: base.
             Load paths:
               Compass::SpriteImporter
               /Users/geonorr/Sites/quasar/public/stylesheets/sass
               /Users/geonorr/Sites/quasar/app/assets/stylesheets
               /Users/geonorr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
               /Users/geonorr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
       on line 3 of /Users/geonorr/Sites/quasar/app/

I am using Rails (3.1.0), Sass (3.1.7), Sass-Rails (3.1.0), Compass (0.11.5)

---

Thanks for the response. Feel like I am getting closer...
Including Compass Master Branch and getting this error:

`gem 'compass', :git  => 'git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass', :branch => 'master'`

Using compass (0.12.alpha.0.d03d529) from git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass (at master) /Users/gnee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:365:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /Users/gnee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/gems/compass-0.12.alpha.0.d03d529/bin/compass (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Users/gnee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:365:in`open'
from /Users/gnee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:365:in `shebang'
from /Users/gnee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:456:in`app_script_text'

Comment: FYI, the compass rails 3.1 branch disappeared. It's very difficult to find information regarding what's happening with this project.

Comment: Ok thats why bundler was failing. Yep all the information on this project is seems deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

1. *= require comments can be seen as a hacky workaround from the perspective of Sass, because Sass has a dedicated language feature for that: the @import directive. @import tells Sprockets what to do. When you are migrating from a Rails 3.0 project, leave all @import statements as they are. At the moment, the only gotcha is "globbing": How to tell Rails/Sprockets to regard also other Sass files than application.css.s(ac)ss.

   Here is [the latest Compass installation guide](https://gist.github.com/1184843) for Rails 3.1. It also tackles the globbing problem.
2. As it is said in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization), `app/assets`, `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets` directories in your app as well as in your gems/engines are included in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`. I verified that +opacity(.5) from the compass/css3 library works as expected if you install compass properly. Which leads us to the next point:
3. The `rails31` branch is merged into `master` now and version 0.12.alpha has been released that should support Rails 3.1. However, this is version is not yet without bugs. So I recommend to rely on the newest master revision:

   `gem 'compass', git: 'git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass', branch: 'master'`
4. The only bug I am encountering at the moment is a "undefined method nil.[]" Exception when trying to compile statements that create **sprites**. See [this issue](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/567). A workaround for that is to set `sass_options = {quite: true}` in your `config/compass.rb`

Further note: I do not have Sass in my Gemfile any more. I think you can remove that dependency when relying on `sass-rails`.

Comment: '@import tells Sprockets what to do'. The Sass-Rails page says nothing really about this. Are there any resources that cover this? Been Googling this to death no luck.

Comment: The compass creator [announced here](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/337#issuecomment-1030655): "What we'll do is make Sass @import directives find things via sprockets. Sass users shouldn't have to use hacky comments to accomplish this behavior. Sass has already implemented this feature, we just need to glue it together." ... and this is the result: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/master/lib/sass/rails/importer.rb